# Using gitlab.com hosted Gitlab, how do I get metrics like "number of commits" in Prometheus?

Tags: gitlab, prometheus

I would imagine this should be rather simple, but after reading the documentation I am confused about what's available at gitlab.com-hosted vs. self-hosted and where there's cpu/memory metrics vs. project metrics like number of commits.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus on the SaaS/hosted version is only available as a [project integration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/prometheus.html) to monitor deployments and typically the Kubernetes cluster.

[Prometheus for a GitLab instance](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/monitoring/prometheus/) is only available for self-managed, because the purpose is to help an administrator monitor their GitLab instance. As a GitLab.com (hosted) user, that doesn't make sense because you're not the one maintaining the GitLab instance.

Docs note: Pretty much everything in the admin section of the docs (`/ee/administration`) is self-managed only as the audience is a GitLab admin.

However, if you're interested, GitLab has setup [Grafana dashboards for GitLab.com](https://dashboards.gitlab.com) which are publicly viewable and make use of the data from their Prometheus.

As to how you get the statistics you want. Hopefully what's available in the UI is what you're looking for.

Things like number of commits is on the main project page. For example, on the [GitLab project](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/), it shows the number of commits, branches, etc.

[image: GitLab project stats]

Other statistical information for a project that might be of interest (linking to the GitLab project as an example):

- [Cycle Analytics](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/cycle_analytics), showing median value of each GitLab flow stage
- [Insights](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/insights), showing mostly historical graphs
- [Charts](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/graphs/master/charts), shows language and commits information including average commits per day
- [Productivity Analytic (docs)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/analytics/productivity_analytics.html)

Note: some of the features may be only available on a paid plan.